# Why is exim not adding the DKIM header to emails?

Tags: email, email-server, exim

My emails used to be getting signed with DKIM in the header. Now if you check the email source it is not signing.

Whatis wrong? How can I debug, what logs can I look at?

```
cat /etc/exim4/conf.d/main/00_local_macros
```

Returns:

```
DKIM_CANON = relaxed
DKIM_SELECTOR = mail
DKIM_DOMAIN = ${sg{${lc:${domain:$h_from:}}}{^www\.}{}}
DKIM_FILE = /etc/exim4/keys/${dkim_domain}/mail.private
DKIM_PRIVATE_KEY = ${if exists{DKIM_FILE}{DKIM_FILE}{0}}
```

The location of the keys:

```
ls -la /etc/exim4/keys/example.co.za/
```

Returns:

```
-rwxr-x--- 1 Debian-exim Debian-exim  887 Mar  7 17:26 mail.private
-rwxr-x--- 1 Debian-exim Debian-exim  305 Mar  7 17:26 mail.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your mainlog to verify which transport is delivering your mail (T= lines).  The only standard transport that signs email is `remote_smtp`.  If mail, is being delivered by a different transport, it won't be signed.

EDIT:  I believe this maybe where your problem is as `${dkim_domain}` likely doesn't contain the value of `DKIM_DOMAIN` :

```
DKIM_DOMAIN = ${sg{${lc:${domain:$h_from:}}}{^www\.}{}}
DKIM_FILE = /etc/exim4/keys/${dkim_domain}/mail.private
```

Try:

```
DKIM_DOMAIN = ${sg{${lc:${domain:$h_from:}}}{^www\.}{}}
DKIM_FILE = /etc/exim4/keys/{DKIM_DOMAIN}/mail.private
```

Although I would recommend not sending from `www` domains so you could define DKIM_DOMAIN as follows.  You could use domain rewriting to remove the `www` portion of the domain, although I would try to avoid getting it there in the first place.

```
DKIM_DOMAIN = ${lc:${domain:$h_from:}}
```

I prefer to use a split configuration, although the single file configuration works if you only have simple modifications.  Any changes I make are new files, with new names.  I have a couple of modified versions of Exim provided configuration files modified to my needs.  This method retains my changes when an Exim upgrade includes configuration changes.  In either case, consider using a revision control system to track your changes.

The user id running exim needs to be able to read the key files, and all directories leading to the files.   However, it should not be able to write or replace the keys.  If you have keys in dedicated directory you can protect it by change the mode to `750`, changing the owner to `root` and the group to `Debian-exim` or whatever group Exim runs as.  Protect the keys likewise, but set the mode to `440` or `640`.

Comment: `2016-04-22 03:22:53 1atPnq-0005I3-JJ => XXX@hotmail.com R=dnslookup T=remote_smtp H=mx3.hotmail.com [65.55.33.135] X=TLS1.2:ECDHE_RSA_AES_256_CBC_SHA384:256 DN="CN=*.hotmail.com" C="250  <E1atPnq-0005I3-JJ@web.XXX.co.za> Queued mail for delivery"` It is using `remote_smtp`though. Do you think the `${sg{${lc:${domain:$h_from:}}}{^www\.}{}}` domain is picking up the entire subdomain: `web.XXX.co.za` instead of just `XXX.co.za`

Comment: @Krauser Yes it will pick up the whole domain. Generally you don't want to send from domains like `web.xxx.example.com`.  Typically you would use `example.com` or possibly `mailing.example.com`. Look at rewriting the domain or setting the `mailname` to the desired domain, or rewriting the From and envelope domain.

Comment: Ok, it's hard to debug what `${sg{${lc:${domain:$h_from:}}}{^www\.}{}}` actually returns.

Comment: @Krauser Exim should log the from address in your logs.  If you don't rewrite the from address, DKIM and SPF validation will not work as you expect.  (I consider email from `www....` to be spam.

Comment: The from is correct `<= info@XXX.co.za U=www-data P=local S=16238 id=b795000adb8aec61964ee`

Comment: @Krauser You can debug with a line like `logwrite = ${sg....}` in an acl.  You can also run exim in debug mode (I do it from the command line).  See the man page and specification.  Check the transport (`T:`) in the `<=` lines. You could try adding a transport filter to save a copy of the outgoing message to the transport.

Comment: Yeah the T line says `remote_smtp`. I checked my version and it has:`Exim version 4.84_2 #2 built 13-Mar-2016 17:47:19` so this all stems from when I updated it used to work before. Maybe I selected `Don't break up into smaller config files`. Should I reconfigure?

Comment: @Krauser  You have the correct transport.  I took a second look at your macro definitions and updated my response.  I also included a comment on split configurations.

Comment: Thank you, now I'm getting something useful: `unable to open private key file for reading: /etc/exim4/keys/XXX.co.za/mail.private`

Comment: My permissions are `root:root` and `644`

Comment: Check the permissions on the directories.  I set the group on the keys, an in your case the key directories to the group the that Exim runs as.,

Comment: I have done that the user is now `Debian-exim` with `644` on keys, `755` on directory. Same error, it seems something strange is going on here...

Comment: Sudo to  `Debian-exim`, cd to `/etc/exim4` and try `ls -lR keys`.  That should give you some hints.   The `keys` directory should have 750 permissions

Comment: Yes!!! Champion. `sudo chmod -R 750 keys/` did the trick. Please update the answer with the permissions issue and I will accept.

Comment: When I use `DKIM_FILE = /etc/exim4/keys/{DKIM_DOMAIN}/mail.private` I get `failed to expand: ${if exists{/etc/exim4/dkim/{${sg{${lc:${domain:$h_from:}}}{^www\.}{}}}.pem}{/etc/exim4/dkim/{${sg{${lc:${domain:$h_from:}}}{^www\.}{}}}.pem}{0}} error message: curly-bracket problem in conditional yes/no parsing: 'yes' part did not start with '{'`.  When I use `DKIM_FILE = /etc/exim4/dkim/${lc:${domain:$h_from:}}.pem`, everything works nicely.

Comment: You can run Exim in test mode to validate your syntax.  Unfortunately, it doesn't get tested until executed.  See the man page for Exim.